# Promesas javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Hola  amigos tengo un problema tengo una promesa ejecutando pero esta no se alcanza a terminar cuando ya el console.log esta imprimiendo, entiendo que se debe usar async await pero no logro entender como peudo implementarlo a mi codigo

```
 function consumoApi() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
             axios.get(`https://dsadsadsadas.dsa/dsa/2019-12-0${i + 1}`).then((response) => {
                response.data.forEach((element) => {
                    data.push(element);
                });
            });
        }
        console.log(data)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recuerda que siempre puedes revisar la [documentación de Javascript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).
Incluso en la [documentación de Axios](https://github.com/axios/axios#example) hay un ejemplo de cómo usar async/await con `get`.

Básicamente, para implementar async/await, debes declarar `async` en tu función, de esta forma, lo que se retornará será una [Promesa](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Using_promises).

```
async function consumoApi() { ... }
```

De esta forma, podrás utilizar `await` dentro de esa función, eso hará que la ejecución del código ***espere*** hasta que los datos provenientes del API estén disponibles. Cabe recalcar, que al usar `await`, el resultado se retornaría de la función, pero en caso de error deberás usar [try...catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/try...catch).

```
// En caso de error, mostrará un 'Uncaught Error'
var response = await axios.get(.....);
```

De esta forma, tu código quedaría así (tarda un poco en obtener los resultados):

```js
var data = [];

async function consumoApi() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    var response = await axios.get(`https://apirecruit-gjvkhl2c6a-uc.a.run.app/compras/2019-12-0${i + 1}`);
    response.data.forEach((element) => {
      data.push(element);
    });
  }
  console.log(data)
}

consumoApi();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

---

Una mejor implementación podría ser así:

```js
function consumoApi() {
  // Nótese el uso de async en la función
  return new Promise(async function(resolve, reject) {

    var data = [];

    try {
      for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        var response = await axios.get(`https://apirecruit-gjvkhl2c6a-uc.a.run.app/compras/2019-12-0${i + 1}`);
        data.push(...response.data);
      }
      resolve(data); // Resolvemos la promesa enviando los datos
    } catch(error) {
      reject(error); // Rechazamos la promesa en caso de error
    }
  });
}

// Llamaremos nuestra función, utilizando la forma de Promesa
consumoApi()
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.26.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```